# How to find Data with Special Character in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to find the data and data containing any of the special characters in the example I have used ( and ) bracket but it could be any. also, I need to exact in an incase-sensitive match with data.
sample data:

```
[
   {
      "cat_id":1,
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryName (Special Box)",
   }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
   {
      "cat_id":1,
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryName (Special Box)",
   }
]
```

While I am using the query-

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
$match:{
"categoryName":{$regex:"categoryName (Special Box)"}
}
}])
```

I got the No data found in the response How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to [escape special characters](https://www.jmp.com/support/help/zh/15.2/index.shtml#page/jmp/escaped-characters-in-regular-expressions.shtml), like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "categoryName": {
                $regex: "categoryName \(Special Box\)"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: how can I use \ inside the input string that is dynamic

Comment: [this](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/js+escape+all+special+characters) is an example on how to do this "dynamically".